# How do I stop lsp-mode from re-indenting my comments after a newline

Tags: lsp-mode, auto-fill-mode

I just installed [lsp-mode](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/) for use with C++. It's reformatting my comments as I type. For example, if I have a doxygen comment like this:

```
/// Blah blah blah ... blah blah the end. [cursor here]
///
class Thing
```

And I hit the return key, it reflows it, something like:

```
/// Blah blah ...
/// blah the end. [cursor here]
```

How do turn this off, or tell it I want a wider text width?

Answer (score 1):

I found this: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1342

A comment there suggested setting `lsp-enable-on-type-formatting` to nil. I did that and re-opened a file, and it worked for me. It was no longer annoying me by reformatting my comments when I typed a newline.

Answer (score 0):

`lsp-mode` doesn’t reindent anything. It is the LSP server that can make these kinds of changes. Read the help files for your LSP server to find out what configuration options is has.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that. I was using eglot before and this wasn't happening, and they both use clangd.